# Setting the enabled of an item in 1 scened based on a selection in another scene

Tags: swift, macos

I would like to enable/disable an item in 1 scene based on a selection (or none) in another scene. This is an OS X app using storyboards.

Here is the setup:

**Window Controller Scene** has a toolbar with multiple toolbar items; the view displays the contents of a **Main Split View Controller Scene**.

**Weeks View Controller Scene** (master view) and
**Games View Controller Scene** (detail view)
Both of these scenes have tables using array controllers.

If a row in the Games View Controller Scene (detail) has a row selected I would like to enable a toolbar item in the Window Controller Scene. If no row is selected, disable the toolbar item. Is this doable and if so, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this in 2 ways.

1. If you are transitioning from your Scene 1 to Scene 2 upon selecting a row from Scene 1. Then you can simply set a boolean var in your scene 2 to true before transitioning and later use this boolean in your viewdidload to set the enabled property.
2. You can always use a UserDefaults to store a boolean value. Toggle this value according to your selection in Scene 1. In scene 2, you can check this boolean value and set the enabled property according.

Hope this helps. :)